# "hover" Selector Does Not Work with Flexbox to Change Dropdown Display to "none"

Tags: html, css

Hovering selector in css is not capable of making the child element disappear with display: none;

I have tried different selectors such as + it did not really work. I am a complete noob sorry for that.

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders */
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #menu{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    #logo{
        height: 70px;
        width: 70px;
    }
    
    div nav{
        display: flex;
      /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
        flex: 1; 
    }
    
    div nav ul{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        background-color: mediumaquamarine;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex: 1; 
      /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
    }
    
    div nav ul li{
        display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
        flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
        justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: blue;
        flex: 1; 
      /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
        position: relative;
    }
    
    div nav ul li a{
        display: flex; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
        flex-direction: column; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
        justify-content: center; /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: orange;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0.5px;
    }
    
    div nav ul li a:hover{
        background-color: #9f7934;
    }
    
    #dropdown{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        top: 60px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #products:hover #dropdown{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180">
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Smiley face" id="logo"> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="products">Ürünler</a>
                        <ul id="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Ürün 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ürün 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ürün 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ürün 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">İletişim</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Child should disappear when products selected. Whenever I use hover on dropdown list i can make them disappear but it does not seem to work for parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target the next sibling element

```
#products:hover + #dropdown
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Width and height apply to all parts of the element: content, padding and borders */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

div nav {
  display: flex;
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
  flex: 1;
}

div nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
}

div nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  /* This flexbox property lets button area to fill-in the remainin space until the logo area */
  position: relative;
}

div nav ul li a {
  display: flex;
  /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
  justify-content: center;
  /* These 3 lines or the align the bottons vertically */
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5px;
}

div nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #9f7934;
}

#dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}

#products:hover+#dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Smiley face" id="logo">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Anasayfa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="products">Ürünler</a>
        <ul id="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Ürün 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ürün 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ürün 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ürün 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">İletişim</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dogukan. Could you please explain why you used ul#dropdown. Why #dropdown does not work?

Tesekkurler Dogukan

Comment: Also it does not work quite the way I wanted. Here is what i want to do. As soon as you move your mouse out of the button that has a dropdown list, dropdown list disappears again.

https://jsfiddle.net/53kdyo4e/

Comment: i wrote a description on codepen. in html code. https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/PXmJPv

Comment: Cok tesekkurler :D - Thanks. I dont have reputation to upvote u :(.

Comment: rica ederim dostum :D

Comment: Dogukan, sitemle ilgili meta datayi kaldirabilirmisin bu mesajdan? sitem hakkinda yazan bilgilerden son zamanlarda bilemedigim yerlerden ddos trafigi aliyorum. Goren amator site filan diye ddos trafigi gonderip duruyor gibi. Cok uzun surmeyen 5, 10 dakikalik ataklar ama arada aliyorum bunlari. Tesekkur ederim.

Comment: bilgim yok malesef